# Preg replace callback

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I am trying to work out how to pop an optional group into a preg_replace_callback but I am having trouble matching the + character

Here is the code I have this far

```
$pattern=preg_replace_callback('~:(?P<_param>[Aa-zZ0-9_\-]+)(?:(P<_mod>[^/]))?~',

    function($matches)
    {
        print_r($matches);
        $key=$matches[1];
        return '(?<'.$matches['_param'].'>'.$matches['_mod'].')';
    }
    ,$subject);
```

This generates the following pattern

```
/category/(?<foo>)/(?<baz>.)+/(?<bar>.)+/(?<harry>.)+/foo
```

For the following string

```
/category/:foo/:baz.+/:bar.+/:harry.+/foo
```

As you can see it's carrying over the . but not the plus, essentially I would like it to carry (into the named _mod capture group) any modifier that I append to a :variable.

I am not very good at regex so I'm amazed to have gotten this far and any help on my quest would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You don't need `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: That's quite an unhelpful comment, perhaps offering an alternative would be more helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a quantifier after the group `_mod`:

```
$pattern=preg_replace_callback('~:(?P<_param>[Aa-zZ0-9_\-]+)(?:(?P<_mod>[^/]+))?~',function($matches){
//                                                                  here ___^
```

question: what do you think `[Aa-zZ]` matches?

I guess you want `[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+` or `[\w-]`

Furthermore, `preg_replace` would suffice here:

```
$pattern = preg_replace('~:([\w-]+)(?:([^/]*))?~', "(?<$1>$2)", $subject);
```